# How to build and deploy dacpac in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am new to Azure devops. Here I have a requirement to do dacpac file build and deployment in Azure devops.can anyone help me to share me the step to step procedure.
I am using visual studio 2017.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

> How to build and deploy dacpac in azure devops

You can use build pipeline to build that and then deploy it using release pipeline.

1. If you developed the sql server project by VS, you can publish it to Azure Devops Repos following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017?view=azure-devops).
2. Then create a build pipeline following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops), you can use classic UI editor without YAML to configure your pipeline.

   1. Select the Azure Devops Git as source. And choose the sql server project published from VS.
   2. Choose the agent you want to use in Agent Job, [Hosted agent or Private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).
   3. Click the `+` in Agent Job to add a task. You can choose the Visual Studio build task, this task will call [msbuild.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019) to build your sql server project.
3. To deploy the output of sql server project, there're many choices. One is to use [`Windows Machine File Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) task to deploy the files in current agent to destination folder in remote machine. You can use this task in Release or even Build Pipeline to do that.

Hope it helps and if I misunderstand anything, feel free to contact me.